# How to display a view when ViewLoads in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have no idea how to use SwiftUI, I just want to present my view when the view controller loads, how can I present it?

```
class AnalyticsVC: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        BarCharts().onAppear()
    }
    
    struct ContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
            BarCharts().onAppear()
        }
    }

    struct BarCharts:View {
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                BarChartView(data: ChartData(points: [8,23,54,32,12,37,7,23,43]), title: "title", style: Styles.barChartStyleOrangeLight)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you'd better start from https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui

Comment: This might help you as well: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit